# Reading data twice after fileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I need to read data twice from the uploaded file. At the moment it reads only one(first) time.
PS(I can't use AllAgentsB = AllAgents)

```
            Stream path = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;              
            ReadAgents(path, AllAgents);
            path.Position = 0;
            ReadAgents(path, AllAgentsB);
```

Comment: Have you tried “seeking” to the beginning of the stream?

Comment: What do mean? How can I do that?

Comment: .seek(0) on your Stream.  Note though that not all streams support “seeking”.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work when I add  `path.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

Comment: Hmm.  That’s what I had to do to read a stream twice.  Merely setting Position wasn’t sufficient.  Sorry I couldn’t be of more help.